# Post request with basic authorisation

Tags: c#, post

I am writing a C# console app to send a POST request with basic authentication to obtain an access token from an api. I have to pass grant_type=password&username=&password= and I am not sure how to pass this in with the post request. So far I have

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

Do I pass the password/username in the content, if so how?  Thanks

Comment: This should ready - grant_type=password&username=(encryptedusername)&password=(encryptedpassword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "your_username"));
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "your_password"));

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri) 
{ 
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters) 
};

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I had something similar to that, so glad I was thinking on the right lines.  I will have to test tomorrow as can't access the server today. Thanks for your help.